# Excel: Search box with conditional formatting, how to keep rows highlighted?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to make a spreadsheet that acts as a tool for marking names off a roll.

I've started by using conditional formatting to highlight a row, by searching a name or id, but every time I start a new search it clears the previous formatting (ie: doesn't keep the previous row searched for highlighted).
How can I achieve this?

[image: image of spreadsheet]

[image: formula used]

Answer (score 0):

The conditional formatting changes according to the value in the `search_box` cell. That is by design. If the value in `search_box` no longer meets the condition, the formatting will be removed. That is the "conditional" part of conditional formatting.

If you want to keep the highlights, you could manually format the found cells, or you could manually add data next to the found cells, like a "found", then add a rule that highlights the row when the cell in the flag column shows "found". Or something along these lines.

Comment: i decided to use a checkbox and format the row to highlight rows if checked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to highlight the row based on the search ID you have included in the grey cell.

You would have to insert a formula conditional formatting rule.

select the entire data-> click home -> conditional formatting -> new rule -> "Use a formula to determine which cells to format".

Insert the following formula: =$B4=$B$2
Where B4 is the cell above 5188 and b2 is the cell you have in grey (your search ID cell).